# @svgr/webpack import xx from 'paths/xx.svg' Error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

@svgr/webpack
import xx from 'paths/xx.svg'
Error:unknown:Unexpected token,

this is new yarn create react-app xx --typescript project,

```
import xxSvg from 'paths/xx.svg';
```

SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token, expected "," (3:22)

Answer (score -1):

You will need loader to load the svg file. Use [File Loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/) with following config to load the svg image.

```
rules: [
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
    use: {
        loader: 'file-loader'
    }
]
```

Comment: I converted svg to component via `@svgr/webpack` for use with the `Icon` component of `ant-design`.